# How do I include a JSP file from a different project into my project

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

How do I include a JSP file from a different project into my project?

```
<%@ include file="./common/webappfooter.jsp"%>
```

The above code does not work.

Answer (score 12):

This works only if the other project is bundled in flavor of a JAR file in `/WEB-INF/lib` folder of the main webapp project and if the JSP file is in turn placed in `/META-INF/resources` folder of the other project.

So, if you have a `/META-INF/resources/common/webappfooter.jsp` in the other project, then the following include should do:

```html
<jsp:include path="/common/webappfooter.jsp" />
```

If you're using a bit self-respected IDE, you can configure it to automatically bundle the other project as JAR of webapp project's `/WEB-INF/lib`. It's unclear what IDE you're using, but in Eclipse it's a matter of adding the other project as *Deployment Assembly* in the main webapp project's properties.

[image]

In Eclipse, to create such a project with the right folder structure prepared, choose the "Web Fragment Project" wizard.