# How to call a JSP from a diff website(project)?

Tags: java, jsp, jspinclude

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I include a jsp file from a diff project into my project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210628/how-do-i-include-a-jsp-file-from-a-diff-project-into-my-project)

How to call a JSP from a diff website(project)?

I am trying to make a common project which would have a header and footer that all my web projects in my firm is going to use.

so I have a jsp at

```
http://localhost:8080/common/webappfooter.jsp
```

and I am trying to get a page in my Sample project to include it.

I beening trying

```
<jsp:include path="http://localhost:8080/common/webappfooter.jsp" />
```

but it does not work

Comment: You're going totally the wrong path as to sharing JSP files between web projects. Check my answer on your previous quesiton how to achieve this properly. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210628/how-do-i-include-a-jsp-file-from-a-diff-project-into-my-project You should split the to-be-shared JSP file out into a standalone web fragment project which you in turn include in all web projects.

Answer (score 0):

You could use JSTL.

```
<c:import url="http://localhost:8080/common/webappfooter.jsp" />
```

Comment: Note that this includes the output of the JSP (like as the webbrowser retrieves), not the source code of the JSP.

Comment: @BalusC Yes, that is true. But, since javaspyman posted the action element(not the include directive) in his code, I assume that is what he wants to do.

Comment: I wouldn't assume that javaspyman really understands what he's actually doing. Based on this question and the previous question on the same subject, he is going the wrong path this way.

Comment: how else do you think I should do this.

Comment: That's already answered in your previous question.

Comment: If you don't want to use JSTL, then you could use a HttpURLConnection object.

Answer (score -1):

Include work in same project, so it won't work here..

You can use iframe to do so..