# How to include remote jsp using <%@ include file %>

Tags: jsp

I want to include a jsp from another project. How do I do that?

I am fine to use  or <%@ include file %>

I tried giving path for the other project, but it did not work.

Assume that the jsp to include is called a.jsp and the jsp that includes a.jsp
is called b.jsp

Comment: You're not giving us much to go on.

Comment: what is the purpose of including the other jsp? what end result are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Possible Duplicate:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11210628/how-do-i-include-a-jsp-file-from-a-diff-project-into-my-project